# How to use SELECT with IF's condition for trigger in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to create a trigger to change value of taille column if NULL.
I know another syntax error with freshman this is a rediculious thing. But, this level is so avanced than me.
You can begin reading the code from her :
 #1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 'select i.id from categorie cat,souscategorie scat,item i,panier p where p.idite=' Ã  la ligne 3.

```
delimiter /
create trigger voiddresstaille before insert on panier for each row
begin
    if new.idite=(select i.id from categorie cat,souscategorie scat,item i,panier p where p.idite=i.id and i.idscat=scat.id and scat.idcat=cat.id and cat.nom='Vêtements & Chaussures') then
        if new.taille='' || new.taille=NULL then
              new.taille='M';
        end if;
    end if;
end /
```

If you don't know the answer please vote up the quostion to help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only 'select' commande is mean you can have a one or more line with your column. But, if you add 'limit 1' in the end of your commande you will get one line.
The point here is, you can't comparing between one value and table of values.
Only if you add to your condition 'in(select....etc)' to check your value in table's values.

So that your code will be like this :

```
delimiter /
create trigger voiddresstaille before insert on panier for each row
begin
    if new.idite in (select i.id from categorie cat,souscategorie scat,item i,panier p where p.idite=i.id and i.idscat=scat.id and scat.idcat=cat.id and cat.nom='Vêtements & Chaussures') then
        if new.taille='' || new.taille=NULL then
              new.taille='M';
        end if;
    end if;
end /
```

Answer (score 1):

your sytnax is wrong.

And i change your query to proper inner joins

You can have **only one** i.id From your Selecft else this ends in an error

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS voiddresstaille ;
delimiter //
create trigger voiddresstaille before insert on panier for each row
begin
    if new.idite = (select i.id 
                    from categorie cat 
                    INNER JOIN souscategorie scat ON scat.idcat=cat.id 
                    INNER JOIN item i ON i.idscat=scat.id 
                    INNER JOIN panier p ON p.idite=i.id 
                    where  cat.nom='Vêtements & Chaussures') then
            if new.taille='' OR new.taille IS NULL then
               SET new.taille='M';
            end if;
    end if;
end //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hi @nbk, i got this after past the code #1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de '/' Ã  la ligne 13. When I delete the extra " / " i got this error  #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Comment: Yes you have to delete the trigger, before adding. see changed answer